# java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! - Android Code Coverage?

Tags: java, android, testing, code-coverage, android-testing

I was using EclEmma coverage tool to test my code coverage. But whenever I run my test cases, It gives me the following error. Can you please tell me how can I solve this error.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

i met a similar question:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

at junit.runner.Version.id(Version.java:5)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.getJUnitVersion(PowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:27
```

the way I fixed it is to move `junit.jar` ahead of `android.jar` in the class path of my eclipse project. The reason is that both `junit` and `android` contains the same package and class for `junit.runner.Version`, so when `android.ja`r is ahead, the class loader  will load this class from `android.jar` but it should download it from `junit.jar`, and thus throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I have met similar problem. Seems like it was because you add a android Jar to your project which is not a Android project.  In my case,I change my project to a Android project and it works well.